# How to use formatR

Tags: r

How to use formatR to get an output like

```
data<-data.frame(response=c(48,31,24,29,46,34,25,31,45,37,27,35,37,39,30,38,45,34,29,32,
                             28,17,19,20,32,18,20,22,35,19,22,24,39,16,19,22,31,15,20,22)
                  ,treatment=rep(c("A","B","C","D"),10)
                  ,subject=rep(c("A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J"),each=4)
                  ,group=rep(c("A","B"),each=20)
                  )
```

from a arbitrary input like

```
data <- data.frame(response = c(48, 31, 24, 29, 46, 
   34, 25, 31, 45, 37, 27, 35, 37, 39, 30, 38, 45, 
   34, 29, 32, 28, 17, 19, 20, 32, 18, 20, 22, 35, 
   19, 22, 24, 39, 16, 19, 22, 31, 15, 20, 22), treatment = rep(c("A", 
   "B", "C", "D"), 10), subject = rep(c("A", "B", 
   "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J"), each = 4), 
   group = rep(c("A", "B"), each = 20))
```

what I want,
- take the 2nd data.frame
- execute  tidy.source(filename, file = filename) and
- get a data.frame in a form like the first data.frame.

If I could choose that formatR ignores these datas, would be also fine by me.

Comment: Your use of commas is a bit unorthodox. However, there were a few double commas now, corrected by me. But please give details how your output should look like, and why you think formatR will do this for you.

Comment: Hi, thx I changed the content of the topic to the right form.

Comment: Just in case somebody wants to give it a try: Note the somewhat confusing naming scheme: @Klaus uses output as the input and wants input as the output.

Comment: I could make the meaning clearer,I guess. Thx for reading.